# Tango depth test does not go well

Tags: google-project-tango

I just found that my tango tablet's depth sensor is not working as expected in my project. Then I took the depth test as instructed in https://developers.google.com/project-tango/hardware/depth-test and found the top right area (about 1/4th of the rectangular ) of the point cloud in the screen are always nearer than the others and full of errors. I tested in different lightings and also tested some clean floor area and found similar errors in that area. So what is wrong with the depth sensor?

Thank you so much!

Siyuan Chen

Comment: It doesn't look like you've provided enough information for the community to diagnose the problem.  Also, you might have better luck on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) since this could be a hardware issue.  Could you at least provide more information about the results of your troubleshooting?

Comment: Hi Sildoreth, thank you for your reply. Yes, I agree it should be some hardware issue. To make my problem more clear, if you open the link at https://developers.google.com/project-tango/hardware/depth-test, you can see the point cloud shown on the screen should be a rectangular if you stand in front of flat wall when the device works well. However in my all tests, the top right part of the "rectangular" was missing. And I can see that missing part are actually have smaller depth value than others. I wonder if there is a way to calibrate it.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for hearing that your depth test failed, from your description, you may need to re-calibrated your devices on depth. right now
please send the request email to :project-tango-help@google.com 
let us see what we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the test again, but this time lock screen rotation first.  Then turn the tablet upside down.  If the errant pixels now appear in the lower left, it is likely a hardware issue.  If they remain in the upper right, it is an environmental issue.  For example, what looks like a flat wall could be slightly bowed.